# Is uploading icons to MyApps on developer.ubuntu.com enough?

Tags: application-development

I submitted an app for review via https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/ There were some icons needed in the process. I've uploaded them. My question is: will these icons somehow be automatically added to my application or should I put them into my program myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the icons you upload are just used in the software center.  If you want icons on your launcher you will need to add them using your .desktop file.